# How to login and register (signup) customer in Magento 1.9 rest api ? and also solve the below error

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, register, rest-api

I am using http://myurl/api/rest/customers and getting the below access denied error even I had set user role for the customer under `SYSTEM > WEBSERVICES > REST` ROLE and also give permission from `SYSTEM>PERMISSION>USERS`.

[image]

I am very confused how to get this error 403:

> access denied as I had done each step to give permission from Magento backend.

Comment: Have you passed the token and key in the header when you hit the API?

Comment: @Gideon hi, If i try to get customer list using REST API i am getting error -> screenshot -> https://snag.gy/3PSxvm.jpg -> URL -> 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/customers. and if i try to get products its working -> screenshot -> http://snag.gy/sePpyw.jpg -> url 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products, can i get help regard customer API error?

Comment: @zus retrieving products don't need any access. However, if to see the list of customers, you must pass the token and key. Please try to use any API client like postman to pass the creds.

Comment: @Gideon okay, correct my token and key value is right. Token -> https://snag.gy/KXzE5W.jpg  key -> https://snag.gy/Mq2BZI.jpg, if right means how can i pass the token and key?

Comment: @Gideon Postman configuration : https://snag.gy/hQlR47.jpg and my token key request source code: https://justpaste.it/2y2e6 screenshot -> https://snag.gy/KXzE5W.jpg

Comment: @Gideon Is my workout right ? Still anything else shall i need to do?

Comment: @zus I think you should follow this: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/using-postman-troubleshoot-restful-api-requests/ or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045800/how-to-use-postman-rest-client-with-magento-rest-api-with-oauth-how-to-get-toke

Comment: @Gideon thank you, now i am  getting customer details. screenshot : https://postimg.cc/67x3Vmqr and https://postimg.cc/JHsMCNt7

Comment: @Gideon By using postman it is working, how can i pass my all values to url, like 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/customers

Comment: @zus why do you need to use this in URL? Usually, APIs are used to develop a mobile application. I just want to know what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Gideon I just want to share my details to Android based application, before that i need to do self test, that's what i am test in URL, FYI -> 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products its return values if i try in URL, now i try with POSTMAN very useful and get everything working now.

Comment: I am glad it works for you @zus

Comment: @Gideon its not completed, in localhost everything working. Live server some issue in oAuth error, i can't able to install oAuth. I cant able ti install oAuth ver 1.0 but there is no issue in oAuth ver 2.0.

Comment: @Gideon so i try to work with oAuth ver 2.0, can you pls help me to get Access Token? My magento ver 1.9.2.3. screenshot : https://snag.gy/oZy09C.jpg

Comment: @zus what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Gideon If i try to install oAuth 1.2.3 into server return error like : /root/tmp/pear/oauth/php_oauth.h:35:40: fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ext/standard/php_smart_str.h"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85079/discussion-between-zus-and-gideon).

Comment: @zus I am sorry I didn't notice your message. Did you get that working?

Comment: @Gideon Finally moving soap v2 and get the response, but response like object, how can i get like XML. Source code:   https://justpaste.it/43kpl

Comment: @zus I am not damn sure about it. But to me it looks like you need to customize the API code to send the response in XML format.

Comment: @zus will this help you? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/response_formats.html

Comment: @zus in the above link it reads, "The format of returned data is defined in the request header". Try changing your header request format.

Comment: @Gideon FYI I am using SOAP. I need xml format by my SOAP.

Comment: @zus you have to use text/xml in the header of your SOAP API call

Comment: @Gideon I am just new to api could you pls help me to alter my code for desired output like xml values. My code : https://justpaste.it/43kpl